# Memory management in appending a string?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an iPhone application in which i am creating an array in the `didfinishlaunch` in the appdelegate. Like this:

```
    for(int i=1;i<53;i++)
        {
            NSString *namestring=[NSString stringWithString:@"avatar"];
           NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
            NSString *pngstring=[NSString stringWithString:@".png"];
            string = [string stringByAppendingString:pngstring];

            namestring = [namestring stringByAppendingString:string];

            NSLog(@"%@",namestring);          
        [avtararray addObject:namestring];


        }
```

working fine.and everywhere i am doing the avatar job with my avatararray in the appdelegate.But in one case when i pop back to the previous view and try to load the string from the array again
 `NSString *avatarstringt=[[appDelegate.avtararray objectAtIndex:i]description];`here it is crashing with a an error

> -[CFString description]: message sent to deallocated instance..

when doing the profile job i know that the leak is in the above loop in the appendingstring code.Can anybody help me to remove this?

Comment: `NSString * namestring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"avatar%d.png", i];` can replace the first 5 lines.

Comment: anyways, there's no error in the program you have provided -- run with zombies and record your reference counts to determine the over-release.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, **Never do this**

```
NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
NSString *pngstring=[NSString stringWithString:@".png"];
string = [string stringByAppendingString:pngstring];
```

---

**The following statements, are redundant**

```
NSString *namestring=[NSString stringWithString:@"avatar"];
NSString *pngstring=[NSString stringWithString:@".png"];
```

and should be written as:

```
NSString *namestring=@"avatar";
NSString *pngstring=@".png";
```

---

You can use as :

```
NSString *namestring=@"avatar";
NSString *numberString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
NSString *pngstring=@"png";

namestring = [namestring stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@.%@",numberString,pngstring];
```

---

**Even the shortest of code :**

```
for(NSInteger i=1;i<5;i++){
    NSString *namestring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"avatar%@.png",@(i)];        
    NSLog(@"%@",namestring);
}
```

As suggested by rmaddy: you can use i as integer, no need of converting it into nsnumber

```
NSString *namestring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"avatar%d.png",i];
```

Comment: Thanks for ur attention..it will be great if u edit my code or give me some snippets..

Comment: In the last code block, why are you wrapping `i` in an `NSNumber`? Just use `%d` in the format string and pass `i` as the argument. Much more efficient.

Comment: @rmaddy: i thought of using a wrapper around... anyways yours suggestion is good.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya It should be`%d`, not `%ld`. The latter is for long integer.

Comment: @rmaddy: I have used NSInteger, and i think it should be `ld` now I dont have mac, xcode to check...

Comment: `NSInteger` is an `int`, not a `long`. The compiler complains if you use `%ld` with `NSInteger`. It's happy with `%d`.

Comment: @rmaddy: Now i am confused, I always see a warning with %d, so i checked documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Comment: @rmaddy: I checked in xcode (through teamViewer) it shuold be %ld, as I am having XCode4.5

Comment: Are you building for iOS or OS X? My check is for iOS.